# Display json data nicely from web api?

Tags: java, android, json

I created an app which pulls json data from an online web api and displays the text of that json data in textview. however, it shows as the raw json data - I would like to take out all the symbols and just display the text in a nice way.

What is this process called please?

Example of json string:

```
{
    "Title": "Up",
    "Year": "2009",
    "Rated": "PG",
    "Released": "29 May 2009",
    "Runtime": "96 min",
    "Genre": "Animation, Adventure, Comedy",
    "Director": "Pete Docter, Bob Peterson",
    "Writer": "Pete Docter (story), Bob Peterson (story), Tom McCarthy (story), Bob Peterson (screenplay), Pete Docter (screenplay)",
    "Actors": "Edward Asner, Christopher Plummer, Jordan Nagai, Bob Peterson",
    "Plot": "Seventy-eight year old Carl Fredricksen travels to Paradise Falls in his home equipped with balloons, inadvertently taking a young stowaway.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Awards": "Won 2 Oscars. Another 69 wins & 69 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk3NDE2NzI4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzE1MzEyMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "88",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    "imdbVotes": "600,265",
    "imdbID": "tt1049413",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

Comment: can you post the json string ?

Comment: pls see original post for update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [FastJson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson).

Step 0.
Import Fastjson into your project.

0.1 - Android Studio Gradle

```
compile 'com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.7'
```

0.2 - Eclipse
Add library
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.2.7/fastjson-1.2.7.jar

Step 1.
Creat Java Objects like

```
public class MyJsonBean {
    private String Title;
    private String Year;
    private String Rated;
    //...
    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        Year = year;
    }

    public String getRated() {
        return Rated;
    }

    public void setRated(String rated) {
        Rated = rated;
    }
    //....
}
```

Step 2.

```
String jsonStr = "Your Json Str";
        MyJsonBean myBean = JSON.parseObject(jsonStr, MyJsonBean.class);
        System.out.println("Title = " + myBean.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Year = " + myBean.getYear());
        System.out.println("Rated = " + myBean.getRated());
```

Step 3.
You can use `myBean.getName()` to get value.

Then, it's done.

Ps. this website can help you create Java Objects
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
[image: like this]
Click `Preview`

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the Raw Json data into a String or you can user `Gson` libraries to convert `Json object` to `Java Object`.

If your Json is like

```
{
  "text" : "value"
}
```

Then create a class

```
public class Text
{
  public String text;
}
```

Then parse json using Gson object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Text parsedText = gson.fromJson(jsonString,
                                        Text.class);
```

Now set `parsedText.text` to your textview

Regards,
Sree

Comment: On a long run, Gson helps you to parse obects very easily. Add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' ` as dependecy in Android studio gradle

Answer (score 0):

**you should parse your json string with this class [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) like this:**

*you have a string object jsonString with this content:*{"Title":"Up","Year":"2009","Rated":"PG","Released":"29 May 2009","Runtime":"96 min","Genre":"Animation, Adventure, Comedy","Director":"Pete Docter, Bob Peterson","Writer":"Pete Docter (story), Bob Peterson (story), Tom McCarthy (story), Bob Peterson (screenplay), Pete Docter (screenplay)","Actors":"Edward Asner, Christopher Plummer, Jordan Nagai, Bob Peterson","Plot":"Seventy-eight year old Carl Fredricksen travels to Paradise Falls in his home equipped with balloons, inadvertently taking a young stowaway.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"Won 2 Oscars. Another 69 wins & 69 nominations.","Metascore":"88","imdbRating":"8.3","imdbVotes":"600,265","imdbID":"tt1049413","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}

```
try {
//parse string

JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(jsonString);

//get data

String title = jso.getString("Title");

int year = jso.getInt("Year");
...
}catch(JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a JSON consumer, which this article covers (and provides source to): https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson

A JSON consumer simply makes it easier for you to manage key:value pairs and (obviously) print them out. You direct the consumer to read the incoming data and it parses it into a handy object map for you to access.

This is even nicer in Groovy, but I know you wanted a pure Java solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't particularly need to create a custom class to parse the JSON using GSON.

You can pass it as a JsonObject and easily parse it from that.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    JsonObject obj = gson.fromJson(JSON_DOCUMENT, JsonObject.class);

    String title = obj.get("Title").getAsString();
    String rated = obj.get("Rated").getAsString();
```

You can even grab JSON nested arrays and grab elements from them.

```
     obj.get("SomeArray").getAsJsonArray();
```

Hope this helps :)